# Hide certain columns based on container size and/or device on ag-Grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am adapting some grids to be 'responsive' and actually found the [dynamic resizing without scroll](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-responsiveness/#dynamic-resizing-without-horizontal-scroll) on the documentation, but this will apply to even on grids on desktop and hide fron right to left which is not desirable.

Is there any way of hiding certain columns based on a weight-like configuration?

The plan-b is to duplicate the column-configuration with another configuration and render the correct one for the available width.

Comment: Is using bootstrap not an option? You can easily achieve this using the bootstrap grid system (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/)

Comment: you could have some directives setup that one is set on container and another on column first is communicating to second telling how much place there is and second trigger hide mechanism if there is not enough space. At least if using media queries is not enough.

Comment: Using ag-grid can't use a custom render as this will just hide the cell not the whole column.